# Flask-SQLAlchemy: User role Models and relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a Flask-SqlAlchemy database model and need users to be linked to a single role. Example roles: "User", "Admin", "Moderator".

Surely I could use a simple relatioship, which just adds a user_role_id Column to the User, but I would also like to track the last modification.

```
class User:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class UserRole:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

class UserRoleLink(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    user_role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user_role.id"), primary_key=True)
    last_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
```

How do I complete this model with the required relationships? Also I would like to ensure, that a User can only have one Role, but Roles can be used as often as required.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should works for you:

```
class User:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class UserRole:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    role_link = db.relationship('UserRoleLink', cascade='all, delete-orphan', uselist=False)

class UserRoleLink(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    user_role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user_role.id"), primary_key=True)
    last_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
```